# Last day of last month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-formatting

I need to get last day of last month in SQL Server in the format "2017-05-31". Does anyone know how to write query for this?

Comment: Function that will return the current date in the format you want is:

`DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2010** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 and 2016 (and 2017 on the horizon) - so which one *are you talking about*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a SQL Server 2010 (to my knowledge).  In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `EOMONTH()`:

```
select eomonth(dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
```

Actually, in any version, it is probably simpler to just do:

```
select dateadd(day, -day(getdate()), getdate())
```

Oh, and then cast to a date to get rid of the time component:

```
select cast(dateadd(day, -day(getdate()), getdate()) as date)
```

Comment: oh my god ..thats what exactly i was looking for....i am new to sql ...thank you so muchhh....

Comment: @Kate Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/sql
Have fun learning ! ;)

Comment: Hi @Gordon, I have a ssis package which doesn't have last_used_date column but i have to create a derived column upload as last day of last month "2017-07-31" , do yo know how to write expression is derived column in ssis package?

Comment: @Kate if this answer solved your issue you have to accept it , read more at [Tour page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)